# How can I configure autofs with indirect map using sshfs?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

How can I configure autofs with an indirect map using sshfs?

What I've done so far:

- added `/servers auto_sshfs` to `/etc/auto_master`
- created `/etc/auto_sshfs` with `* -fstype=sshfs &:/`
- Ran `sudo automount -vc`

I'm assuming that either I have fstype flag incorrect, in the wrong place or I some how need to let autofs know of sshfs.